# autoexp.dat not parsing union?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2005

I have an in-place vector class that's defined like so:

```
template<class T>
class svectorbase
{
    // ...
protected:
    union 
    {
        char* m_char;
        T* m_t;
    } m_elems;
    size_t m_maxsize;
    int m_elemCount;
};

template<class T, size_t maxsize>
class svector : public svectorbase<T>
{
protected:
    char m_elems[sizeof(T) * maxsize]; // gets passed to base class
};
```

(Don't ask why they didn't just create a `T m_array[maxsize]`... sigh)

I'm trying to create an autoexp.dat entry for it in VS2005 because that structure makes it hard to look at in the debugger.  I've got as far as:

```
svector<*>{
    preview 
    (
        #("size=",$e.m_elemCount,"/",$e.m_maxsize)
    )
    children
    (
        #array
        (
            expr : ($c.m_elems.m_t)[$i],
            size : $c.m_elemCount
        )
    )
}
```

...but while the size attribute shows up correctly, the array is populated with `(error):0` entries.

I'm probably doing something obvious to do with the union, but can't see the forrest for the trees.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a member variable called `m_elems` in your base class, and another member variable called `m_elems` in the derived class.

The `$c.m_elems` in `$c.m_elems.m_t` refers to the derived class's `char` array, not the base class's union.

Comment: Ah!  What a dupe I am.  I changed the name in the child class and it works now.  I didn't really want to edit this wtf-y code but there you go.

Answer (score 2):

You can try explicitly casting m_t to T*:

```
children
(
    #array
    (
        expr : ((($T1*)($c.m_elems.m_t))[$i],
        size : $c.m_elemCount
    )
)
```

I'm not near a dev machine now so there may be syntax errors here - but hopefully it gets the idea across.

Comment: Hadn't seen the $T1 constant before, nice.